# Esxi 6.0, Last login of users on virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

0

Good day! I have about 700 virtual machines running Windows 2016. We are using vmvare 6.0. Need to know the last login of users? How can i do this?

all virtual machines are separated from each other, there is no domain.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

> Need to know the last login of users?

If you are referring to log in of users to the 700 Virtual Machines (VMs), ESXi and all Virtual Machine Monitors (VMMs) regard VMs as "black box" sources of load.  They don't know how many users are logged in to a VM nor what they are doing.  VMMs deal in CPU usage, disk usage, network load and so on.  In fact the best way to think of ESXi's view of the system is to consider what the view of the system is from the standpoint of the (Pentium) processor.  It also has no idea how many users are logged in or what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the task is not relevant, thank you all